# How to install anydesk in Ubuntu terminal 14.04 ? Os type 32 bit

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

Please someone tell me How to install **Anydesk** in Ubuntu terminal 14.04 ?

OS type 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Since `anydesk` isn't found in the Ubuntu repositories, ( see https://packages.ubuntu.com/search ), the only way available to you is to go to https://anydesk.com/download and follow their instructions.

If their instructions don't include Ubuntu 14.04, consider upgrading to a more recent, Long-Term Support version, 16.04LTS or 18.04LTS. Ubuntu 14.04 is no longer supported.